# Has the Block Cache Settings from Drupal 8 been back-ported to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, blocks, caching, performance

I noticed in Drupal 8 there are options to cache a block:

[image: block cache settings]

I was wondering if these options exist in Drupal 7 with a module? Has the feature been back ported? or was it a contrib module to begin with?

Comment: The D7 version is [Block Cache Alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter) I think. It doesn't have contextual caching, I believe that's very new

Comment: @David Barratt Where, in the Drupal Web Admin UI, are the Drupal 8 Block Cache settings shown in the screen - i.e what would the general URL path be, please?

Comment: Question about location of your screenshot of block caching asked here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274874/block-caching-in-drupal-8-is-there-a-setting-to-turn-this-off-per-block-block

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to backport. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7's `DRUPAL_CACHE_CUSTOM` and https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts.